# OroPlatform: wrong timezone with GreaterThan constraint js validator

Tags: orocrm, orocommerce

### Context

On a Symfony form, I need to restrict a date field to avoid entering a date earlier than the current date.

I have seen in the Symfony official documentation that I can use the `GreaterThan` constraint. Here is my code :

```php
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 * @Assert\DateTime()
 * @Assert\GreaterThan("now UTC+2")
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="start_date")
 */
private $startDate;
```

I have setup my timezone the following way:

- In the OroPlatform dashboard : `System > Configuration > Localization`
- I have put the timezone in `php.ini` of the Symfony Web Server

My timezone is `Europe/Paris`

### Issue

I have done all the requirements described in the Context section. But, the js validator not working.

[image]

I'm living in France so my timezone is `Europe/Paris`. If I do a `dump(new \Datetime('now'))` the current datetime value is `10H48`

How to adapt the js red alert to set the current js timezone to `Europe/Paris` ?

I have tried to run these commands `symfony console cache:clear` and `symfony console oro:localization:dump` but it doesn't change the timezone in the red message.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found what I have done wrong.

If your server and your Oro app localization is correctly configured. You don't have to force the locale in the entity constraint.

So, change :

```php
/**
* @var \DateTime
* @Assert\GreaterThan("now UTC+2")
*
* @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="start_date")
*/
private $startDate;
```

to

```php
/**
* @var \DateTime
* @Assert\GreaterThan("now")
*
* @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="start_date")
*/
private $startDate;
```

Don't forget to clear your cache : `symfony console cache:clear`